# How to push cursor to the right while giving input just like we do in a NOTEPAD

Tags: c

I am trying to make a notepad like output window.
Problem is if we enter LEFT ARROW the cursor moves to the left ,but how to move it again to the right hand side without deleting the the content.
Also the text gets deleted if we tap SPACE-BAR.

Try out the code if you want <>

```
int main()
{
    int k,l;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n \t\t ** WELCOME TO C NOTEPAD ** \n\n START FROM HERE  -  :) \n\n    ");
    while(1)
{
    k=getch();
    if(k==0xE0)  // TO check if we enter arrow keys
    {
        l=getch();
        switch(l)
        {
            case 75 : printf("\b"); break;  // LEFT ARROW
            //case 77 : printf("\r"); break;  //RIGHT ARROW

            default:  continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
         switch(k)
        {
            case 13 : printf("\n"); break;  // New line after pushing ENTER key
            case 8 : printf("\b"); break;   // BACK SPACE
            case 9 : printf("\t"); break;   // TAB
            case 27: system("cls");         // Clear screen after pushing ESCAPE key

                    printf("\n\n * PRESS ANY KEY TO START AGAIN \t *PRESS 'ESC' TO EXIT");
                            if(getch()==27)
                                exit(0);
                            else
                                main();

            case 127 :  printf(" "); break; // DELETE 

            default:   printf("%c",k);
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Where do you store the content?

Comment: By filling the line with spaces?

Comment: After a while, you will probably want some sort of cursor library, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library).

Comment: @UnholySheep Never really thought about it. I just do it for fun. Please suggest something if you can :)